# SpringBoot @WebMvcTest is loading non-dependent beans when @ComponentScan is used along with @SpringBootApplication

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am using **SpringBoot 2.3.3.RELEASE** and I have following web controllers and Services.

```
myapp
  - controllers
      - ProductController
      - OrderController
  - services
      - ProductService
      - OrderService
```

`ProductController` only depends on `ProductService` and `OrderController` only depends on `OrderService`.

Following is my SpringBoot main entrypoint class:

```
package com.sivalabs.myapp;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

I have an `@WebMvcTest` controller for testing `ProductController` as follows:

```
@WebMvcTest(controllers = ProductController.class)
class ProductControllerTest {
    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    private ProductService productService;
   
    //some tests
}
```

Everything works perfectly fine with this configuration.

I am trying to use some external library with Spring components which has different package name, so I want to override `@ComponentScan` as follows:

```
package com.sivalabs.myapp;
import com.somelib.BeanConfig;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = {Application.class, BeanConfig.class})
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

When I include `@ComponentScan` on my main entrypoint class and run my `@WebMvcTest` based test `ProductControllerTest` then in addition to `ProductService` SpringBoot is trying to initialise `OrderService` also. Ideally `ProductControllerTest` should not load `OrderService` as `ProductController` doesn't depend on `OrderService`. Is it a bug?

**Workarounds:**

1. If I use `@ComponentScan` the way it is used on `@SpringBootApplication` meta-annotation and include `basePackageClasses` it is working fine.

```
package com.sivalabs.myapp;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(excludeFilters = { @Filter(type = FilterType.CUSTOM, classes = TypeExcludeFilter.class), @Filter(type = FilterType.CUSTOM, classes = AutoConfigurationExcludeFilter.class) },
basePackageClasses = {Application.class, BeanConfig.class})
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

2. Instead of adding `@ComponentScan` on main entrypoint class if I add another configuration class and add `@ComponentScan` on that class then it's working fine.

```
package com.sivalabs.myapp.config;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = {BeanConfig.class})
public class AppConfig {

}
```

Is it a bug in component scanning process or is it working as expected?

Comment: Add a separate `@Configuration` class for the `@ComponentScan`. It is working as expected as the application class (the `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class) is loaded and processed. Any additional annotations on there will be processed and activated as well. There is no way to exclude them, unless they are on external `@Configuration` classes (your "workaround" #2).

Answer (score 1):

It working as expected.
@SpringBootAplication already have @ComponentScan with filters, and redeclare it as in workaroud #1 doesn't make sense, right?

Problem With original code is that @ComponentScan overrides exclude filters applied inside @SpringBootApplocation annotation. And stuff is not excluded, so when @WebMvc tries to request part of context using filters it fails, and entire context is loaded.

Just check what beans are initialized for context in each scenario. And stick to solution 2. @SpringBootTest will scan packages where application class is places, and any additional packages should be scanned by configurations. That is even more flixible right? :)